# How can I center check box and the label in the form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I center the text and the checkbox which has the caption "Address same as above". I use bootstrap and tried to center it but nothing helped.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="hr-sect col-xs-12">Home Address</div>             
    <div class="form-group required">
     <div class="col-xs-12 center-block" >
     <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chkIsSameHomeAddress" id="chkIsSameHomeAddress"  class="AddressCheckBoxShowGroup checkbox" value="false">            
     </div>
      <label for="chkIsSameHomeAddress" class="control-label col-xs-4">Address same as above</label>  
     </div>                             
    </div>
```

Below is the out put I get I need to center the control and the label.
[image]

Comment: Do not post screenshots. Post the appropriate CSS instead, or better yet, create a working snippet. Then we can fiddle around and help.

Comment: Try to put the `label` element next to `checkbox` input.

Answer (score 0):

Stripping it right back you can do this:

(the border, line-height and font-size are there simply to exaggerate the vertical-align)

```css
.verticalMiddle {
  border: solid black 1px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>Home Address</h1>
<div class="verticalMiddle">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label >Address same as above</label>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you

```css
   .checkbox.form_div label{
        padding-left: 0;
    }
   .form_div input{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="hr-sect col-xs-12">Home Address</div>             
    <div class="form-group required col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 checkbox form_div text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkIsSameHomeAddress" id="chkIsSameHomeAddress"  class="AddressCheckBoxShowGroup checkbox" value="false">            
            <label for="chkIsSameHomeAddress" class="control-label">Address same as above</label> 
        </div>
    </div>
```